# Iterating over a vector of type some class in another class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

please help me out with C++ code, I have commented whatever I want to do, I have a class DEF which has a vector of type ABC. ABC has some members. I have another class ZYX in which I want to iterate over members of class ABC using the vector in class DEF. Also I cannot change classes ABC and DEF

```
class ABC{
   public:
    //some members and other stuff
}

class DEF{
    public:
    ....
    vector<ABC> cdf;    //ABC is some other class

}



//includes all the necessary part including DEF and ABC
class ZYX{

   //iterate over members of ABC using cdf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about access modifiers?
there are keyword like `private`, `protected` and `public` which declare how variables in your classes can be accessed from outside. Read up on it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/
The default access modifier in c++ classes is private. Which makes variables you declare inside the class inaccessible from the outside.

Easiest solution is to make the specific variable you want to use `public`

```
class DEF
{
public:
  vector<ABC> cdf;    //can be accessed from outside
}
```

Not elegant but effective. Probably the better way is to declare a function returning a reference to the variable you want to access like:

```
class DEF
{
private:
  vector<ABC> cdf;    //can NOT be accessed from outside
public:
  vector<ABC>& get_cdf() { return cdf; }  //can be accessed from outside
}
```

Comment: The members are all public. I am looking for a code to iterate over... in class ZYX. I have no control over class DEF or ABC

Comment: Then why present the layout of your classes, try to formulate questions as precise as possible? For iterating over std containers consider the cpp language reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/

Comment: My problem is that the vector contains the type as some other class, whose members I want to access, not some int, I have problem with syntax also, where to use -> and where '.' , so some code snippet would better help me which uses class as types like I have mentioned.

Comment: When accessing a member of a vector element of arbitrary type use an expression like myvector[index].mymember. I will not explain the difference between "->" and "." If you do not know this you do not have a basic understanding of the c++ language syntax. There are so many good tutorials out there. Just read up on them. This is a good starting point http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/